# I want to click in some specific window with this code but it doesn't work properly

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to click in some specific window with this code but when i tried to compile this it doesn't work, i can't figure out this so  want some help from you guys.

```
int x = 1555;
int y = 193;
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, x, y, 0, 0);
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, x, y, 0, 0);
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, x, y, 0, 0);
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, x, y, 0, 0);
```

Comment: so what is the error when you try to compile?

Comment: Now it clicks but not in my pos.

Comment: Please define "doesn't work properly."

Comment: It doesn't just click on the position.

Comment: So *where* do you mean it to click? Without [MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-mouse_event) specified, those numbers are interpreted as mickeys relative to the last reported position.

Answer (score 1):

As comments, you will need to add other flags:`MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE`, and another one: MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE. And you need to convert the coordinates to normalized absolute coordinates between 0 and 65,535

```
int x = 1555;
int y = 193;
DWORD fScreenWidth = ::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN) - 1;
DWORD fScreenHeight = ::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN) - 1;
DWORD dx = MulDiv(x,65535,fScreenWidth);
DWORD dy = MulDiv(y,65535,fScreenHeight);
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE| MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE, dx, dy, 0, 0);
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP | MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE| MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE, dx, dy, 0, 0);
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE| MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE, dx, dy, 0, 0);
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP | MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE| MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE, dx, dy, 0, 0);
```

In addition, [`mouse_event`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-mouse_event):

> This function has been superseded. Use [`SendInput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput) instead.

```
int x = 1555;
int y = 193;
DWORD fScreenWidth = ::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN) - 1;
DWORD fScreenHeight = ::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN) - 1;
DWORD dx = MulDiv(x, 65535, fScreenWidth);
DWORD dy = MulDiv(y, 65535, fScreenHeight);

INPUT input[4] = { 0 };
input[0].type = input[1].type = input[2].type = input[3].type = INPUT_MOUSE;
input[0].mi.dx = input[1].mi.dx = input[2].mi.dx = input[3].mi.dx = dx;
input[0].mi.dy = input[1].mi.dy = input[2].mi.dy = input[3].mi.dy = dy;
input[0].mi.dwFlags= input[2].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN| MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE;
input[1].mi.dwFlags = input[3].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP| MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE;

SendInput(4,input,sizeof(INPUT));
```

Comment: Integer math is inappropriate. It never rounds; it simply truncates. Multiplying a truncated result (as you are proposing) only exaggerates the error. There's no reason to avoid [MulDiv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-muldiv).

Comment: Yes, this is my fault. Fixed